# heavy operation in Service Async Task freezes the screen

Tags: android, service, upload, android-asynctask

I've developed an application and one of its aims is to upload a file to the server. On average the file is quite large and upload takes a lot of time, so to make sure it'll be processed till the end, I moved the critical part of IO to the IntentService. From the IntentService for every single upload there's an AsyncTask started which does the IO job. Unfortunately the screen scrolling gets freezed several times while doing the upload in the background. I thought that a combination of IntentService+AsyncTask should be enough...
I'd be grateful for any suggestions how to solve it..

Comment: Want to post some code? Specifically the `IntentService` and the `AsyncTask`? Also are you doing any work in any of the `AsyncTask`s methods that are run on the UIThread (`onPostExecute`, `onPreExecute`, and `onProgressUpdate`)?

Comment: Just to check, you're doing all the heavy processing in doInBackground with the AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misusing IntentService. I am assuming that you are calling `AsyncTask.execute(...)` from `IntentService.onHandleIntent(Intent)`.

IntentService was created to perform background tasks one at a time on a non-UI thread. This means that `onHandleIntent(Intent)` is invoked from a background thread and should not be creating AsyncTasks. Furthermore, once `onHandleIntent(Intent)` finishes (and it does so immediately if all you do is start an AsyncTask) the service is a candidate for being shut down.

I know that this doesn't directly answer your questions but it may point to the causes of the issue.
Note that if you need to be able to handle multiple requests concurrently then your best bet is just to extend Service and enqueue a work request onto an Executor in `onStartCommand(...)`.

[EDIT] For more information on proper usage of `IntentService` check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) out.

Comment: thanks for your answers, all I got from them is that the following solution should be appropriate to accomplish file upload task
http://vmix.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/android/VmixSDK/src/com/vmix/android/vmixsdk/rds/FileUploadService.java

Comment: That's a good start but there is rarely a reason for creating your own Thread objects in Android (or any Java 5 or later). Managing your own threads can be risky, especially for newer programmers. For instance, the Thread.stop() method is deprecated and doesn't actually do what you'd want it to do. You should consider the Executor framework (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) for this type of work. Not only does it offer superior thread management but it also guarantees certain things related to thread-safety that most people do not understand.